# Is there a way to use newline characters in vue.js

Tags: vue.js, newline, backslash

I would like to use a newline character (**\n**) in a string in **vue.js**

For example:

```
created() {
    this.buttons = [
      {
        id: 1,
        text: "Button \n 1",
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        text: "Button \n 2",
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        text: "Button \n 3",
      },
```

Is there another way to do this, because that does not work?
I don't want to use `<pre`, `white-space: pre` or `white-space: pre-wrap`.

Thank you in advance

Comment: why don't you want to use these? Is there any problem with it?

Comment: is it possible to use these in javascript strings?

Comment: ah I see - sorry read over this!

Comment: because I want to use these at specific spaces

Comment: See below answer - does this answer your question?

Comment: Please check my answer below

Comment: `\n` !== `<br>`. so without changing them to `<br>`'s or using CSS white-space prop on the element, is not possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You can use `<br>` (HTML code) instead of `\n`.

And in the HTML use it this way:

`<div v-html="text">`

**[Edit]**

Please see the following [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5Lsj0q8a/).

Comment: is it possible to use these in javascript strings?

Comment: What you mean by "these javascript strings" ?

Comment: @MrBlender Please check my latest comment. It might help you.

Comment: Thank you very much, this helped me out

Comment: Yeah, I hope I really do. Good luck.

Comment: and, is there a way to, for example when I include '<div>' in the code, not to run this as html code? but only the line breaks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238812/discussion-between-mrblender-and-richie-permana).

Comment: Sure. Just check the discussion link you've mentioned before.

Answer (score -1):

try this:

```
text: "Button\ 3"
```

ust enter a back-slash and keep on - hopefully this works now!

Comment: now I understand, thank you

Comment: would be very nice if you accept my answer if it helped you out :)

Comment: sorry, it doesn't work this is the code:

Comment: text: "Button" + "<br>" + "3",

Comment: and the result I get in the browser is this:

Comment: Button<br>3 (result)

Comment: you can also try with "\\n"

Comment: I am sorry, still doesn't work

Comment: I just get this as a result: Button \n 3

Comment: updated it again!

Comment: nope, i get an error: unnecessary escape character

Comment: No. `\\n` will not gonna work. What it would do probably just gonna escape the `\`.

Comment: Please test the code that you about to give to someone else because it might be a big misleading to others.

Or AT LEAST, check the facts before.

Comment: So, what I want to do, is using an escape character in a vue js string (not html) to display a newline.

Comment: Have a func in JS to convert any `\n` (or whatever identifier) to `<br />`, then pass it into an element with `v-html`.